# Creating an templated Array of templated Arrays of different templated objects

Tags: c++, templates, arrayofarrays

Hey so I am currently working on a very simple ecs and I want to store all of my `Components`, of which there are different types, in arrays, of which there are also different types, and all these arrays in one larger array. 
Like this:

```cpp
ComponentArray< ComponentArray< Component > > components;
```

Now I read about this and apparently I have to create a base class for `ComponentArray` as well as for `Component` and let the `MainArray` have pointers to the base class.
So I think the declaration should look like this:

```cpp
ComponentArray< ComponentArrayBase< ComponentBase* >* > components;
```

And in the initialization in another implementation file (because it is a static class and has template member functions so I have to make the implementation a `.inl` file and can't initialize the array there) :

```cpp
ComponentArray< ComponentArrayBase< ComponentBase* >* > ComponentManager::components{/*creating some arrays here*/};
```

My Array class looks like this:

```cpp
template<typename ComponentType>
struct ComponentArrayBase{};

template<typename ComponentType>
struct ComponentArray : ComponentArrayBase<ComponentType>
{
    ComponentType array[maxEntitys];

    ComponentType& operator[](unsigned int index)
    {
        return array[index];
    }
};
```

And my `Components` look like this:

```cpp
struct ComponentBase{};

struct PositionComponent : ComponentBase
{
    //some member variables
};
```

Where I want to use it e.g:

```cpp
template<typename ComponentType>
ComponentType& ComponentManager::getComponent(Entity e, unsigned char index)
{
    return *(*(components[index])[e]);
}
```

When compiling I get the following error:

```cpp
error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘ComponentArrayBase<ComponentBase*>’)
     return *(*(components[componentArray])[e]);
```

I am not sure if the things I said all make sense so thanks a lot for your answers

Che

Comment: Why do you want a special type for your arrays of components? What functionality does it add over a standard library container, such as `std::vector`?

Comment: I need a wrapper around an array so I can let the wrapper inherit a base class in order to put different types of arrays in one bigger array. Inside the wrapper I don't want to use std::vector because then I would loose a lot of the advantages of fast iterating through an array. What I could use is std::array but I don't see any reason since I just need to index it and nothing more.

Comment: @Che " don't want to use std::vector because then I would loose a lot of the advantages of fast iterating through an array" huh? Iterating over `std::vector` is as fast as it gets. What are you talking about?

Comment: Okay but I sinply don't need a vector because I don't want to dynamically allocate memory. I just need a fixed size array without any extra fancy stuff.

Comment: `std:array` is an easier solution with `.at()` if you want bounds checking. It's a nice mix of C++11 and `std::array`.